# The web user to have access to only one database

Tags: sql-server, iis-7.5

I have few web sites running in IIS 7.5 and each one is mapped to its own related database, using the `connectionStrings` section in each one of the config files. The string is using "Integrated Security=SSPI" and everything is working fine so far, users can read and write to their respective dbs. The IIS and the SQL Server are on the same machine and the SQL is set for mixed authentication.

I want to set  `Integrated Security=false` and add `user=mySpecifDb;pwd=test123` to the string, but it doesn't work. The web site throws a db connection error. I've created the user "mySpecifDb" using the SSMS and followed all the instructions so far. I can log into the SSMS using the credentials "mySpecifDb" and "test123" and I can read and write to the selected database and only to it exclusively. I can't access any other db using these credentials and this is what I want. In the IIS 7.5 all websites are using the DefaultAppPool. I dont know where to go from this point.

EDIT:  This is the real connection string with the real credentials. As mentioned before I can log in SSMS using them, and read/write to AutoParkDemo db only.If I just change "true" to "SSPI" then all works.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
   <add name="AutoPark" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=AutoParkDemo;Integrated Security=false;user=apmDemo;pwd=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

EDIT:

```
Server Error in '/Manager' Application.
Login failed for user 'apmDemo'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'apmDemo'.
Stack Trace: 

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'apmDemo'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +642
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1089
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6785863
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +207
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +375
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +749
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +504
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +118

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +459
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +51

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.]
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +300
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +327
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +94
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +248
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +618
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps() +23
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists() +40
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext db) +168
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema) +80
   AutoParkManager.Models.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() in c:\AppVS2013\AutoPark\AutoParkManager\Models\IdentityModels.cs:12
   AutoParkManager.Controllers.AccountController..ctor() in c:\AppVS2013\AutoPark\AutoParkManager\Controllers\AccountController.cs:22

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AutoParkManager.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +147
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12639055
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: Please quote the error message

Comment: Can you show us the full `connectionstring` you use with all parameters?

Comment: yes, show the exact connection string, and the exact error message, and it is probably very simple...  connection strings have to be just right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to create a new local windows user on the server, add that user to the SQL database (with correct permissions).  Then create a new app pool using this new identity and assoicate the one web site with this new app pool.  You would leave the Integrate Security as True.

If you really want to specify the user in the config, then as Martin and Dennis commented we would need full error message and connection string (minus the password)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree this would be a better solution. Unfortunately I was not able to make it work. In the end it does not access the db.

Comment: I know you said you were able to log in with the mySpecifDb user via Studio Mgmt, but it almost sounds like the sql server is setup as "Windows Authentication" and not mixed mode.

Try this connection string
`<add name="AutoPark" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=AutoParkDemo;User ID=mySpecifDb; Password=test123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: It is mixed b/c in another (WPF) project the string connection and the credentials do work. Anyway, I decide to go with your "A better solution..." cause it is also what I want to do in the end, to have each website using its own pool, isolation, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Change you `connectionstring` like below and try again. Take off the `Integrated Security=false;` and specify `Persist Security Info=True;`

```
 <add name="AutoPark" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=AutoParkDemo;Persist Security Info=True;user=apmDemo;pwd=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```